# How to control the hair to be outside or inside the icosphere?

Tags: hair

I am trying to make a particle with a hair on its surface but unfortunately the tails got in to the opposite side. How to make these tails be outside like in the figure (B)?
Thank you.

[image]

[image: A. my blender]
[image: B. the required shape]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotate the *instance object* (the "big" particle) 180 degrees on the X-axis (in edit mode):

[image: Rotate]

Comment: oh on edit mode! It worked. Thank you so much! ヽ(ヅ)ノ

Comment: No problem. Remember - particles are instanced based on the object's origin point (the "orange dot") - moving the object relative to its origin point (in edit mode) will change how/where the particle is instanced.

Answer (score 0):

select your object, Tab -> edit mode, A -> select all, Mesh-> normals -> flip

[image]